# failing to run piped commands in rexec in tcl scripting

Tags: scripting, tcl

I am trying to run piped commands in `rexec` on tcl scripting am getting below error

```
rexec "/bin/ps -Ao pid,%cpu,%mem,bsdstart,cputime,state,args --sort=-%cpu | head -51" 
returned error: Illegal chars in command}
```

Comment: Tcl doesn't have a `rexec` command. Where did you get it from? Would a regular `exec` command (without the quotes around the args) not work for you?

Comment: Does ps accept a `%` in its arguments at all?

Comment: @Donal: Yes, when I run the command as `exec /bin/ps -Ao pid,%cpu,%mem,bsdstart,cputime,state,args --sort=-%cpu | head -51`, it produces something reasonable.